# Nested If Statements and Command RD

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm working with a nested if statement to delete directories if they meet a certain criteria. This is part of a for loop to check all directories in a given location. Variable `%JDcalc%` represents the difference between today's julian day and the directory's julian day. Variable `%fdate%` is the directory name. The errorlevel is deteremined by the following:

```
echo.%fdate% | findstr /C:"OE"
```

This nested if statement works:

```
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (if %JDcalc% GEQ 31 (echo DELETE) else (echo KEEP)) else (if %JDcalc% GEQ 14 echo DELETE)
```

As soon as I switch `echo DELETE` to `rd %fdate%` the batch script outputs, "The system cannot find the specified file."

```
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (if %JDcalc% GEQ 31 (rd %fdate%) else (echo KEEP)) else (if %JDcalc% GEQ 14 rd %fdate%)
```

If I use a simpler if statement like `if %JDcalc% GEQ 14 (rd %fdate%)` it works fine.

EDIT: Below is the script in question.

```
@echo off


cd /d C:\Batch\Maximus\Dailies

:TODAYS_JULIAN_DAY
    set /a JD=2458939
        ::a calculation that determines this number is usually here
        ::above is the julian day for 3.30.2020



:FOR_LOOP_FOLDER_NAME
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
        SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
        set fdate=%%a
            ::fdate is set to the date in the directory name
            ::with a naming convention of yymmdd

        call :SUBROUTINE
        ENDLOCAL
        )
    GOTO END_BATCH



:SUBROUTINE
    set folyy=%fdate:~0,2%
    set folmm=%fdate:~2,2%
    set foldd=%fdate:~4,2%

    set /a "folyy=1000020%folyy% %%10000,folmm=100%folmm% %% 100,foldd=100%foldd% %% 100"
    set /a folJD=foldd-32075+1461*(folyy+4800+(folmm-14)/12)/4+367*(folmm-2-(folmm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((folyy+4900+(folmm-14)/12)/100)/4
    set /a JDcalc=JD-folJD



    echo.%fdate% | findstr /C:"OE"

    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (if %JDcalc% GEQ 31 (rd %fdate%) else (echo KEEP)) else (if %JDcalc% GEQ 14 rd %fdate%)

    GOTO :eof



:END_BATCH

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: If the variables are being calculated inside a FOR command block, then you need to use Delayed Expansion.  Please read [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). As it stands your question does not provide a [mcve].

Comment: Delayed expansion is on.

 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  set fdate=%%a

  call :SUBROUTINE
  ENDLOCAL
  )

The if statement is under the :subroutine label.

Comment: As I said in my previous you need to provide a [mcve].  If you are not going to show us enough code to reproduce the problem nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the original post to provide a minimal reproducible example. It's trimmed down a bit, but I'm not certain if I could've simplified further.